# Get related instagram tags

Tags: instagram-api

Is it possible to get related tags on Instagram via the API?

You can get a tags data by doing a GET request on

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

But is it possible to get related tags? so if I searched for webdesign it might return websitedesign etc

Comment: did you check their [API documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/)?

Comment: Yeah, couldn't find anything about related tags though. Only endpoints I can see are tag-name & search. I'll double check though.

Comment: Yup, that's all the functionality they offer - that's all you have access to.  You might have to create your own 'relationships' (between searched tag and related ones) and when a user searches a tag, you automatically do other searches for the related tags in the background.